# ReactJS - Map for state array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, web

I am creating a finance website but having trouble because .map is not executing on a state array.I have been banging my head on the wall for the pass two days. I am thinking that it is something really small

Here is the `GET` call I make to populate the array and set the state.

```
.then(() => {
            var transactions = [];
            axios.get("http://localhost:5000/transactions").then(res => {
                res.data.transactions.transactions.forEach(function(txn, idx) {
                    transactions.push({name: txn.name, amount: txn.amount, date: txn.date});
                    // item.push("hey");
                });
            });
            this.setState({transactions: transactions, balance: content.balance});
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Then my render method looks like this

```
render() {
        var list = this.state.transactions.map((item, id) => {
            return (
                <VerticalTimelineElement
                    className="vertical-timeline-element--work"
                    contentStyle={{ background: 'rgb(33, 150, 243)', color: '#fff' }}
                    contentArrowStyle={{ borderRight: '7px solid  rgb(33, 150, 243)' }}
                    date={item.date}
                    iconStyle={{ background: 'rgb(33, 150, 243)', color: '#fff' }}
                    key={id}
                >
                    <h3 className="vertical-timeline-element-title">{item.name}</h3>
                    <h4 className="vertical-timeline-element-subtitle">${item.amount}</h4>
                </VerticalTimelineElement>
            );
        });

        return (
            <VerticalTimeline>
                {list}
            </VerticalTimeline>
        );
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: There is nothing that is getting rendered and the map method is not even running even when there are items in the transaction array.

Comment: Please show a sample of how the map initially was like

Comment: I don't think i understand what you mean. This is the exact code.@cr05s19xx

Comment: Also, I noticed that you're not updating your state in the `.then` block. You should probable move your call to `setState()` inside the `axios.get().then()`

Comment: Sorry, I did not include the call back that everything is wrapped in.

Comment: Still, when `setState` is called, `transactions` might be empty because `axios.get` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `axios.get` runs asynchronously, the call to `setState` will probably run before `transaction` has any items in it. The call to `axios.get` should be moved up into the `axios.get().then()` block:

```
.then(() => {
    var transactions = [];
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/transactions").then(res => {
        res.data.transactions.transactions.forEach(function(txn, idx) {
            transactions.push({name: txn.name, amount: txn.amount, date: txn.date});
            // item.push("hey");
        });
        this.setState({transactions: transactions, balance: content.balance});
    });
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Also, note that using an item's index within an array as a key is not the best practice and might lead to unexpected results if the array is reordered or if items are added or removed. Per the [docs](http://Keys%20should%20be%20stable,%20predictable,%20and%20unique.%20Unstable%20keys%20(like%20those%20produced%20by%20Math.random())%20will%20cause%20many%20component%20instances%20and%20DOM%20nodes%20to%20be%20unnecessarily%20recreated,%20which%20can%20cause%20performance%20degradation%20and%20lost%20state%20in%20child%20components.):

> Keys should be stable, predictable, and unique. Unstable keys (like those produced by Math.random()) will cause many component instances and DOM nodes to be unnecessarily recreated, which can cause performance degradation and lost state in child components.

Comment: This should be wrong since your repeatedly calling setState within the foreach function. The transaction array reference doesn't change so not all updates may reflect on the display.

Comment: I accidentally moved the call to `setState` one line too high! You're correct: `setState` should be called after the `forEach`, I've fixed my code now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
const {transactions: collection } = res.data.transactions
const transactions = collection.map(({ name, amount, date }) => ({ name, amount, date }));

this.setState({transactions, balance: content.balance});
```

I too think you need to move this within you `.then` block.

While agree hooks would be much better, try this.

Let me know how you get on!

Answer (score -1):

Try using React hooks. Already forgot the old way.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
...
const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState(() => {
   const temp = [];
   axios.get("http://localhost:5000/transactions").then(res => { 
      res.data.transactions.transactions.forEach(function(txn, idx) {
          temp.push({name: txn.name, amount: txn.amount, date: txn.date});
      });
   });
   return temp;
});
```